# I Can't See the Highlighted State of My Custom When I Push it To Get a New View

Tags: animation, button, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am reading many posts about `UIViewController` managing but I can't find the solution to my problem. I am making an iPhone game. I have three screens (menu, game play and scores) constructed into the Interface Builder and from three `UIViewController` classes. Into the main menu I have two custom buttons that allow to go to the game play screen or to the scores screen. Actually I am using the next method to navigate but when I use it, even it changes the screen and takes me to the game play, I can't see the highlighted state of the custom button. Must I change the views like this? How can I show the custom state of my buttons? How can I show an animation while the views are changing?

```
- (IBAction)gotoPlayViewController:(id)sender {

 //Navigation logic may go here.
 PlayViewController *playViewController = [[PlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayViewController" bundle:nil];

 self.view = playViewController.view;

 [playViewController release];
}
```

Thanks for readding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use UINavigationController, don't you?

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances of it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and also makes it easier for the user to navigate that content.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/).
Here is the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

UINavigationController also provides a very easy way to add the slide transition you want.

---

Have fun!

Comment: I have a doubt about UINavigationController. I don't want to use the navigation bar, I just want to change the view using custom buttons. Should I use the UINavigationController anyway?

Comment: You can use UINavigationController without a navigation bar. I think it's best to use UINavigationController indeed. A custom back button is also possible, I'm sure. :)

Comment: Can you link me a tutorial where I can see a sample code? I am reading an Apple forum discussion about this (http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1485164) and they talk about use beginAnimations: and commitAnimations: methods. What do you think about it? Using an UINavigationController is the best way to do what a want?

Comment: Just create an empty Navigation Based project. That is awesome sample code. =D

Comment: I am trying to test this example (http://johnnytrops.com/blog/wp/?p=224). In a moment, when I have tested it, I will write here the results.

Comment: Finally, I have tested the example complete and it works. However, I had to fix one line into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (didFinishLaunching: is actually deprecated). Before adding hierarchically the rest of the view controllers, to return to the root view you have to call the switchToController: like this: [self switchToController:@"RootViewController" animated:NO];. Thank you for your help Time Machine.